# Is there any drawback in resting?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

In Legends of Grimrock your party can rest to recover energy and health. Is there any drawback abusing it?

Comment: I would have thought it would consume food quickly while resting, but after some experimentation, it seems to consume it at no greater rate than if you were just walking around. Surprising!

Comment: @Sterno Do you personally get hungry from sleeping/resting lol?

Comment: @ChrisHateZ Given that resting in this game really means "sitting still and accelerating time", yes, I get more hungry in real life as time passes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another negative aspect of resting is that it expends your hunger level much more quickly than playing at normal speed.

Think of it as the game increasing the play speed by a few [units], anything affected by time is affected by resting.

Comment: Yeah, I seem to be noticing this more as I get deeper in the dungeon. When the question was originally asked, I rested for about 60 seconds on the first level of the dungeon, and the hunger level didn't move. It makes me wonder if hunger increases at a greater rate as you descend the dungeon.

Comment: I did some experimentation for [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62506/3062) and it looks like resting accelerates time to 4x speed, which likely means you're using 4x the food you would have in the same amount of normal time. Not too bad a drawback.

Answer (score 3):

The only negative thing that can happen while you're resting is that monsters can attack you,of course if you find a safe place to rest (which i suggest you do) then you shouldn't have problem.

Answer (score 1):

Resting can also cause some monsters in previously cleared areas to respawn, this is particularly noticeable on  the lower levels like level 6: trapped.