# How often do the healing crystals refresh?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

How often do the glowing blue auto-save crystals refresh? I've accepted the fact that I need to abuse their healing/resurrection powers to keep my band of merry prisoners alive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't take too long. Assuming all of the healing crystals refresh at the same rate as the one I tested on (and this definitely fit the ballpark for what I saw throughout the game), they refresh as follows:

- Refresh after 30 seconds of resting.
- Refresh after 2 minutes of normal time.

This also implies that the ratio between "resting time" and "normal time" is 4:1.